# Programming Question to find lowestMaxVisits in Array

Tags: algorithm

Happy Holidays. I was given a question to solve in less than o(n^2). Given a list of integers, where each number represents the marker in a trail and the runner runs from one marker to another marker and after all the sprints, we need to find the lowest max visits of the marker.

For example, given an array like [1,5,2,7,3,10], we have to return the marker 3 as it is the lowest marker where the runner has crossed maximum times.

```
package io.sort;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class LowestMaxVisitsNumberInArray {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(1);
        list.add(5);
        list.add(2);
        list.add(7);
        list.add(3);
        list.add(10);
        int [] arr = new int[10];
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        long smillis = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        for(int i=0; i<list.size()-1; i++){
            int start = list.get(i)-1;
            int end = list.get(i+1)-1;
            if(start > end){
                int temp = start;
                start = end;
                end = temp;
            }
            for(int j=start; j<=end; j++){
                arr[j]++;
            }
        }
        int maxVisits = -1;
        int index = -1;
        for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
            if(arr[k] > maxVisits){
                index = k;
                maxVisits = arr[k];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Here is the final array"+Arrays.toString(arr));
        long emillis = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
        System.out.println("Time taken---"+ (emillis-smillis));
        System.out.println("Here is the highest---"+(index+1));
    }
}
```

Here is my program which is o(n^2). Is there a better way to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the integers in array bounded? As I see from your code, the max mark is 10! Is it right? If so then your code is O(n) where n is the number of markers!

Comment: There are n markers and n-1 runs. At each run from one marker to the next the runner might pass O(n) markers. Somehow your algorithm needs to make note of that. Based on that (rather superficial, I admit) analysis, I'm not sure whether there's anything better than an O(n^2) algorithm.

Comment: This was asked in hackerrank, and half of the test cases pass and the other half timed out, so I thought maybe there is a better way.

Comment: For inspiration, visit [this problem](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-point-where-maximum-intervals-overlap/). Do you see similarity?